# How to read ggforest and significances for the cox model?

Tags: statistical-significance, cox-model

I run [ggforest](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggforest.html) on a cox model and I wonder now, how I have to interpret the output:

[image: img]

Here, several factors of the variable country are shown. I stumble over the fact, that only countries with very few amounts (Lithuania, Macedonia and Slovenia, yet, Japan e.g. does not) show significances while countries with a lot of units like Italy and South Africa do not provide significances.
How do I have to understand the last column?

edit: Output of

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time = time, event = status) ~ 
    position_in_unit + country + unit_type + version_no + pos + 
        production_year, data = df_cox1, robust = TRUE)

  n= 4266, number of events= 3808 

                                  coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)  robust se       z Pr(>|z|)    
country?                     6.486e-01  1.913e+00  8.443e-01  6.755e-01   0.960 0.336958    
countryAlbania              -1.375e-01  8.715e-01  7.924e-01  5.448e-01  -0.252 0.800697    
countryAustralia            -1.172e+00  3.097e-01  3.739e-01  5.604e-01  -2.092 0.036456 *  
countryBrazil                5.784e-01  1.783e+00  7.948e-01  5.373e-01   1.077 0.281681    
countryBulgaria              8.689e-02  1.091e+00  4.096e-01  5.426e-01   0.160 0.872781    
countryCroatia              -4.393e-01  6.445e-01  5.779e-01  6.317e-01  -0.696 0.486739    
countryCzech Republic        2.337e-01  1.263e+00  4.229e-01  5.820e-01   0.402 0.687948    
countryDenmark              -1.101e+00  3.326e-01  3.658e-01  5.418e-01  -2.032 0.042164 *  
countryEgypt                 9.548e-01  2.598e+00  5.253e-01  5.829e-01   1.638 0.101418    
countryFinland              -1.071e+00  3.426e-01  4.602e-01  6.082e-01  -1.761 0.078160 .  
countryGermany              -4.623e-01  6.298e-01  3.501e-01  5.306e-01  -0.871 0.383657    
countryGreece               -8.345e-01  4.341e-01  3.579e-01  5.340e-01  -1.563 0.118157    
countryHungary              -5.246e-01  5.918e-01  3.652e-01  5.361e-01  -0.979 0.327810    
countryIceland              -7.643e-01  4.657e-01  3.813e-01  5.482e-01  -1.394 0.163285    
countryIndia                -4.836e-01  6.166e-01  3.600e-01  5.367e-01  -0.901 0.367583    
countryItaly                -7.942e-01  4.519e-01  3.758e-01  5.503e-01  -1.443 0.148909    
countryJapan                 6.287e-01  1.875e+00  1.089e+00  5.641e-01   1.115 0.265052    
countryLithuania            -1.445e+00  2.358e-01  6.139e-01  5.664e-01  -2.551 0.010740 *  
countryMacedonia             1.760e+00  5.811e+00  1.063e+00  5.371e-01   3.276 0.001052 ** 
countryMalaysia             -6.192e-01  5.384e-01  3.895e-01  5.514e-01  -1.123 0.261409    
countryNetherlands           6.590e-01  1.933e+00  4.049e-01  5.516e-01   1.195 0.232144    
countryNew Zealand           2.178e-01  1.243e+00  5.709e-01  6.747e-01   0.323 0.746800    
countryNorway               -8.852e-01  4.126e-01  3.564e-01  5.347e-01  -1.655 0.097826 .  
countryPoland               -5.351e-01  5.856e-01  3.725e-01  5.384e-01  -0.994 0.320277    
countryPortugal             -8.723e-01  4.180e-01  3.569e-01  5.347e-01  -1.631 0.102815    
countryQatar                -1.121e-01  8.939e-01  4.007e-01  5.619e-01  -0.200 0.841798    
countryRussian Federation    3.858e-01  1.471e+00  4.246e-01  5.672e-01   0.680 0.496444    
countrySchweiz               2.626e-01  1.300e+00  1.068e+00  5.384e-01   0.488 0.625795    
countrySerbia               -3.720e-01  6.893e-01  5.306e-01  5.869e-01  -0.634 0.526133    
countrySlovakia              1.001e-01  1.105e+00  4.596e-01  6.305e-01   0.159 0.873880    
countrySlovenia             -1.346e+00  2.603e-01  4.541e-01  6.008e-01  -2.240 0.025083 *  
countrySouth Africa          3.426e-01  1.409e+00  3.492e-01  5.318e-01   0.644 0.519441    
countrySpain                -1.284e-01  8.795e-01  3.672e-01  5.370e-01  -0.239 0.810985    
countrySweden               -5.642e-01  5.688e-01  4.139e-01  5.792e-01  -0.974 0.330031    
countrySwitzerland          -6.150e-01  5.406e-01  3.524e-01  5.335e-01  -1.153 0.248940    
countryTunisia               8.887e-01  2.432e+00  1.068e+00  5.535e-01   1.606 0.108375    
countryTurkey               -3.135e-01  7.309e-01  3.540e-01  5.351e-01  -0.586 0.558043    
countryUnited Arab Emirates -9.516e-01  3.861e-01  4.320e-01  6.156e-01  -1.546 0.122159    
countryUnited Kingdom        1.644e+00  5.174e+00  1.122e+00  5.988e-01   2.745 0.006054 ** 
version_no??                -2.422e+00  8.879e-02  1.042e+00  2.728e-01  -8.877  < 2e-16 ***
version_no1                 -3.496e+00  3.033e-02  1.541e+00  5.582e-01  -6.262 3.79e-10 ***
version_no10                -4.304e+00  1.351e-02  1.468e+00  3.635e-01 -11.842  < 2e-16 ***
version_no12                -3.851e+00  2.126e-02  1.447e+00  2.936e-01 -13.117  < 2e-16 ***
version_no13                -3.768e+00  2.310e-02  1.449e+00  3.041e-01 -12.392  < 2e-16 ***
version_no14                -4.565e+00  1.041e-02  1.624e+00  4.432e-01 -10.300  < 2e-16 ***
version_no16                -3.807e+00  2.220e-02  1.448e+00  3.267e-01 -11.655  < 2e-16 ***
version_no17                -1.794e+00  1.662e-01  1.609e+00  4.038e-01  -4.443 8.85e-06 ***
version_no18                -3.955e+00  1.916e-02  1.451e+00  3.142e-01 -12.589  < 2e-16 ***
version_no19                -3.597e+00  2.741e-02  1.437e+00  2.478e-01 -14.513  < 2e-16 ***
version_no2                 -3.418e+00  3.279e-02  1.540e+00  5.573e-01  -6.133 8.65e-10 ***
version_no20                -3.525e+00  2.947e-02  1.455e+00  4.167e-01  -8.459  < 2e-16 ***
version_no21                -3.313e+00  3.642e-02  1.426e+00  1.638e-01 -20.218  < 2e-16 ***
version_no22                -2.483e+00  8.350e-02  1.477e+00  3.396e-01  -7.311 2.65e-13 ***
version_no23                -3.654e+00  2.588e-02  1.439e+00  2.728e-01 -13.395  < 2e-16 ***
version_no24                -4.080e+00  1.691e-02  1.447e+00  3.473e-01 -11.747  < 2e-16 ***
version_no25                -5.072e+00  6.271e-03  1.492e+00  3.898e-01 -13.012  < 2e-16 ***
version_no26                -4.168e+00  1.549e-02  1.449e+00  3.801e-01 -10.965  < 2e-16 ***
version_no27                -4.150e+00  1.577e-02  1.450e+00  3.636e-01 -11.412  < 2e-16 ***
version_no28                -3.652e+00  2.594e-02  1.469e+00  4.029e-01  -9.063  < 2e-16 ***
version_no29                -4.265e+00  1.405e-02  1.461e+00  3.925e-01 -10.865  < 2e-16 ***
version_no3                 -3.600e+00  2.731e-02  1.484e+00  4.148e-01  -8.679  < 2e-16 ***
version_no30                -3.911e+00  2.003e-02  1.487e+00  4.376e-01  -8.937  < 2e-16 ***
version_no31                -4.537e+00  1.071e-02  1.469e+00  4.068e-01 -11.152  < 2e-16 ***
version_no32                -4.237e+00  1.445e-02  1.490e+00  4.346e-01  -9.749  < 2e-16 ***
version_no33                -4.496e+00  1.115e-02  1.497e+00  4.564e-01  -9.852  < 2e-16 ***
version_no4                 -4.837e+00  7.929e-03  1.562e+00  5.592e-01  -8.650  < 2e-16 ***
version_no5                 -3.940e+00  1.945e-02  1.486e+00  4.137e-01  -9.523  < 2e-16 ***
version_no6                 -3.946e+00  1.932e-02  1.480e+00  3.980e-01  -9.916  < 2e-16 ***
version_no7                 -3.701e+00  2.469e-02  1.472e+00  3.806e-01  -9.725  < 2e-16 ***
version_no8                 -3.873e+00  2.080e-02  1.484e+00  4.602e-01  -8.416  < 2e-16 ***
version_no9                 -4.132e+00  1.606e-02  1.504e+00  5.048e-01  -8.185 2.73e-16 ***
version_noAH                -3.224e+00  3.980e-02  1.624e+00  6.091e-01  -5.293 1.20e-07 ***
version_noAI                -3.113e+00  4.448e-02  1.555e+00  5.758e-01  -5.406 6.43e-08 ***
version_noAJ                -1.721e+00  1.789e-01  1.611e+00  5.277e-01  -3.261 0.001110 ** 
version_noAK                -3.463e+00  3.133e-02  1.524e+00  4.996e-01  -6.931 4.18e-12 ***
version_noAL                -3.754e+00  2.342e-02  1.530e+00  5.332e-01  -7.041 1.91e-12 ***
version_noXX                -4.619e+00  9.860e-03  1.507e+00  4.400e-01 -10.497  < 2e-16 ***
pos?                         5.580e-02  1.057e+00  1.506e-01  1.500e-01   0.372 0.709963    
pos1                        -1.117e-01  8.943e-01  1.231e-01  1.167e-01  -0.957 0.338417    
pos10                        9.550e-02  1.100e+00  1.520e-01  1.369e-01   0.698 0.485483    
pos11                        1.460e-01  1.157e+00  1.603e-01  1.666e-01   0.876 0.381025    
pos12                        3.476e-01  1.416e+00  1.645e-01  1.738e-01   2.000 0.045532 *  
pos13                        1.631e-01  1.177e+00  1.730e-01  1.693e-01   0.963 0.335375    
pos14                        6.381e-02  1.066e+00  1.770e-01  1.780e-01   0.358 0.720015    
pos15                        2.723e-01  1.313e+00  1.801e-01  1.686e-01   1.615 0.106313    
pos16                       -5.672e-02  9.449e-01  1.829e-01  1.802e-01  -0.315 0.752910    
pos17                        3.711e-02  1.038e+00  1.843e-01  1.668e-01   0.223 0.823906    
pos18                       -1.375e-01  8.715e-01  1.869e-01  1.890e-01  -0.727 0.466920    
pos19                        2.193e-01  1.245e+00  1.906e-01  1.966e-01   1.116 0.264594    
pos2                         9.314e-02  1.098e+00  1.224e-01  1.155e-01   0.806 0.420024    
pos20                       -6.294e-03  9.937e-01  2.031e-01  1.961e-01  -0.032 0.974394    
pos21                       -5.700e-02  9.446e-01  2.111e-01  1.893e-01  -0.301 0.763315    
pos22                       -3.089e-01  7.343e-01  2.197e-01  2.924e-01  -1.056 0.290768    
pos23                       -1.127e-01  8.934e-01  2.243e-01  2.233e-01  -0.505 0.613855    
pos24                        3.717e-02  1.038e+00  2.436e-01  2.425e-01   0.153 0.878191    
pos25                       -1.168e-02  9.884e-01  2.443e-01  2.267e-01  -0.052 0.958892    
pos26                       -3.724e-02  9.634e-01  2.368e-01  2.838e-01  -0.131 0.895607    
pos27                        3.215e-03  1.003e+00  2.554e-01  3.094e-01   0.010 0.991709    
pos28                       -5.776e-02  9.439e-01  2.508e-01  3.091e-01  -0.187 0.851766    
pos29                       -5.838e-02  9.433e-01  2.654e-01  2.711e-01  -0.215 0.829518    
pos3                         1.204e-01  1.128e+00  1.218e-01  1.136e-01   1.059 0.289438    
pos30                       -2.164e-01  8.054e-01  2.908e-01  3.303e-01  -0.655 0.512462    
pos31                       -1.756e-02  9.826e-01  3.040e-01  3.255e-01  -0.054 0.956990    
pos32                       -4.603e-01  6.311e-01  3.205e-01  2.814e-01  -1.636 0.101911    
pos33                       -3.535e-01  7.023e-01  3.310e-01  2.715e-01  -1.302 0.192958    
pos34                        4.818e-01  1.619e+00  3.459e-01  2.760e-01   1.746 0.080875 .  
pos35                        8.048e-02  1.084e+00  3.670e-01  3.700e-01   0.218 0.827809    
pos36                        1.035e+00  2.815e+00  4.093e-01  3.864e-01   2.678 0.007402 ** 
pos37                       -1.438e-01  8.660e-01  4.682e-01  5.805e-01  -0.248 0.804322    
pos38                       -1.161e+00  3.132e-01  7.254e-01  4.690e-01  -2.476 0.013304 *  
pos39                       -9.507e-01  3.865e-01  7.214e-01  6.853e-01  -1.387 0.165358    
pos4                         5.110e-02  1.052e+00  1.263e-01  1.175e-01   0.435 0.663758    
pos40                        5.205e-01  1.683e+00  1.009e+00  6.743e-01   0.772 0.440134    
pos41                        2.798e-01  1.323e+00  1.038e+00  2.246e-01   1.246 0.212859    
pos42                        4.384e-01  1.550e+00  1.010e+00  1.320e-01   3.322 0.000895 ***
pos43                       -8.881e+00  1.391e-04  2.866e+02  1.013e+00  -8.766  < 2e-16 ***
pos5                         4.826e-02  1.049e+00  1.301e-01  1.211e-01   0.398 0.690305    
pos6                         1.076e-01  1.114e+00  1.346e-01  1.247e-01   0.863 0.388107    
pos7                         8.903e-02  1.093e+00  1.405e-01  1.316e-01   0.677 0.498645    
pos8                         2.199e-01  1.246e+00  1.437e-01  1.461e-01   1.505 0.132387    
pos9                         1.548e-01  1.167e+00  1.497e-01  1.444e-01   1.072 0.283657    
production_year2.015         2.169e+00  8.747e+00  1.173e+00  4.491e-01   4.829 1.37e-06 ***
production_year2.016         2.270e+00  9.677e+00  1.122e+00  4.320e-01   5.255 1.48e-07 ***
production_year2.017         2.582e+00  1.322e+01  1.143e+00  4.347e-01   5.940 2.86e-09 ***
production_year2000          9.028e-01  2.466e+00  1.550e+00  5.658e-01   1.596 0.110577    
production_year2001          1.910e+00  6.756e+00  1.363e+00  8.974e-01   2.129 0.033267 *  
production_year2002          5.756e-01  1.778e+00  1.129e+00  4.499e-01   1.279 0.200793    
production_year2003          1.247e+00  3.481e+00  1.151e+00  5.023e-01   2.483 0.013029 *  
production_year2004          1.467e+00  4.337e+00  1.145e+00  4.977e-01   2.948 0.003200 ** 
production_year2005          1.728e+00  5.628e+00  1.147e+00  5.046e-01   3.424 0.000617 ***
production_year2006          1.827e+00  6.216e+00  1.082e+00  3.810e-01   4.795 1.62e-06 ***
production_year2007          2.225e+00  9.250e+00  1.066e+00  3.395e-01   6.553 5.66e-11 ***
production_year2008          2.046e+00  7.740e+00  1.037e+00  2.629e-01   7.783 7.10e-15 ***
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 11 rows ]
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                            exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
country?                    1.913e+00  5.228e-01 5.090e-01  7.189447
countryAlbania              8.715e-01  1.147e+00 2.996e-01  2.535236
countryAustralia            3.097e-01  3.229e+00 1.033e-01  0.928785
countryBrazil               1.783e+00  5.608e-01 6.221e-01  5.111894
countryBulgaria             1.091e+00  9.168e-01 3.766e-01  3.159628
countryCroatia              6.445e-01  1.552e+00 1.869e-01  2.222715
countryCzech Republic       1.263e+00  7.916e-01 4.038e-01  3.952632
countryDenmark              3.326e-01  3.007e+00 1.150e-01  0.961780
countryEgypt                2.598e+00  3.849e-01 8.289e-01  8.143456
countryFinland              3.426e-01  2.919e+00 1.040e-01  1.128317
countryGermany              6.298e-01  1.588e+00 2.226e-01  1.782049
countryGreece               4.341e-01  2.304e+00 1.524e-01  1.236433
countryHungary              5.918e-01  1.690e+00 2.070e-01  1.692322
countryIceland              4.657e-01  2.147e+00 1.590e-01  1.363723
countryIndia                6.166e-01  1.622e+00 2.153e-01  1.765416
countryItaly                4.519e-01  2.213e+00 1.537e-01  1.328754
countryJapan                1.875e+00  5.333e-01 6.207e-01  5.664970
countryLithuania            2.358e-01  4.242e+00 7.768e-02  0.715474
countryMacedonia            5.811e+00  1.721e-01 2.028e+00 16.653090
countryMalaysia             5.384e-01  1.857e+00 1.827e-01  1.586360
countryNetherlands          1.933e+00  5.174e-01 6.557e-01  5.697717
countryNew Zealand          1.243e+00  8.043e-01 3.313e-01  4.665901
countryNorway               4.126e-01  2.424e+00 1.447e-01  1.176816
countryPoland               5.856e-01  1.708e+00 2.038e-01  1.682302
countryPortugal             4.180e-01  2.392e+00 1.466e-01  1.192081
countryQatar                8.939e-01  1.119e+00 2.972e-01  2.688721
countryRussian Federation   1.471e+00  6.799e-01 4.839e-01  4.470437
countrySchweiz              1.300e+00  7.691e-01 4.526e-01  3.735580
countrySerbia               6.893e-01  1.451e+00 2.182e-01  2.177623
countrySlovakia             1.105e+00  9.048e-01 3.212e-01  3.803010
countrySlovenia             2.603e-01  3.841e+00 8.020e-02  0.845095
countrySouth Africa         1.409e+00  7.099e-01 4.967e-01  3.994384
countrySpain                8.795e-01  1.137e+00 3.070e-01  2.519679
countrySweden               5.688e-01  1.758e+00 1.828e-01  1.770147
countrySwitzerland          5.406e-01  1.850e+00 1.900e-01  1.538054
countryTunisia              2.432e+00  4.112e-01 8.219e-01  7.195974
countryTurkey               7.309e-01  1.368e+00 2.561e-01  2.086281
countryUnited Arab Emirates 3.861e-01  2.590e+00 1.155e-01  1.290441
countryUnited Kingdom       5.174e+00  1.933e-01 1.600e+00 16.733713
version_no??                8.879e-02  1.126e+01 5.202e-02  0.151551
version_no1                 3.033e-02  3.297e+01 1.016e-02  0.090580
version_no10                1.351e-02  7.402e+01 6.626e-03  0.027545
version_no12                2.126e-02  4.705e+01 1.195e-02  0.037790
version_no13                2.310e-02  4.330e+01 1.273e-02  0.041916
version_no14                1.041e-02  9.602e+01 4.369e-03  0.024822
version_no16                2.220e-02  4.504e+01 1.170e-02  0.042122
version_no17                1.662e-01  6.015e+00 7.534e-02  0.366824
version_no18                1.916e-02  5.220e+01 1.035e-02  0.035461
version_no19                2.741e-02  3.648e+01 1.687e-02  0.044559
version_no2                 3.279e-02  3.049e+01 1.100e-02  0.097754
version_no20                2.947e-02  3.394e+01 1.302e-02  0.066677
version_no21                3.642e-02  2.746e+01 2.642e-02  0.050214
version_no22                8.350e-02  1.198e+01 4.292e-02  0.162466
version_no23                2.588e-02  3.865e+01 1.516e-02  0.044170
version_no24                1.691e-02  5.915e+01 8.559e-03  0.033396
version_no25                6.271e-03  1.595e+02 2.921e-03  0.013463
version_no26                1.549e-02  6.457e+01 7.352e-03  0.032620
version_no27                1.577e-02  6.342e+01 7.732e-03  0.032159
version_no28                2.594e-02  3.855e+01 1.178e-02  0.057147
version_no29                1.405e-02  7.115e+01 6.511e-03  0.030334
version_no3                 2.732e-02  3.661e+01 1.211e-02  0.061589
version_no30                2.003e-02  4.993e+01 8.494e-03  0.047213
version_no31                1.071e-02  9.338e+01 4.825e-03  0.023770
version_no32                1.445e-02  6.918e+01 6.167e-03  0.033878
version_no33                1.115e-02  8.967e+01 4.559e-03  0.027277
version_no4                 7.929e-03  1.261e+02 2.650e-03  0.023726
version_no5                 1.945e-02  5.142e+01 8.644e-03  0.043758
version_no6                 1.932e-02  5.175e+01 8.858e-03  0.042156
version_no7                 2.469e-02  4.050e+01 1.171e-02  0.052065
version_no8                 2.080e-02  4.809e+01 8.438e-03  0.051253
version_no9                 1.606e-02  6.228e+01 5.970e-03  0.043185
version_noAH                3.980e-02  2.512e+01 1.206e-02  0.131338
version_noAI                4.448e-02  2.248e+01 1.439e-02  0.137479
version_noAJ                1.789e-01  5.590e+00 6.359e-02  0.503291
version_noAK                3.133e-02  3.191e+01 1.177e-02  0.083428
version_noAL                2.342e-02  4.271e+01 8.234e-03  0.066587
version_noXX                9.860e-03  1.014e+02 4.162e-03  0.023359
pos?                        1.057e+00  9.457e-01 7.880e-01  1.418884
pos1                        8.943e-01  1.118e+00 7.115e-01  1.124133
pos10                       1.100e+00  9.089e-01 8.413e-01  1.438846
pos11                       1.157e+00  8.642e-01 8.347e-01  1.604132
pos12                       1.416e+00  7.064e-01 1.007e+00  1.990290
pos13                       1.177e+00  8.495e-01 8.447e-01  1.640572
pos14                       1.066e+00  9.382e-01 7.519e-01  1.510905
pos15                       1.313e+00  7.616e-01 9.435e-01  1.827185
pos16                       9.449e-01  1.058e+00 6.638e-01  1.344998
pos17                       1.038e+00  9.636e-01 7.484e-01  1.439057
pos18                       8.715e-01  1.147e+00 6.018e-01  1.262273
pos19                       1.245e+00  8.031e-01 8.471e-01  1.830482
pos2                        1.098e+00  9.111e-01 8.752e-01  1.376483
pos20                       9.937e-01  1.006e+00 6.766e-01  1.459404
pos21                       9.446e-01  1.059e+00 6.518e-01  1.368880
pos22                       7.343e-01  1.362e+00 4.140e-01  1.302348
pos23                       8.934e-01  1.119e+00 5.768e-01  1.384005
pos24                       1.038e+00  9.635e-01 6.452e-01  1.669482
pos25                       9.884e-01  1.012e+00 6.339e-01  1.541215
pos26                       9.634e-01  1.038e+00 5.524e-01  1.680465
pos27                       1.003e+00  9.968e-01 5.470e-01  1.839782
pos28                       9.439e-01  1.059e+00 5.150e-01  1.729930
pos29                       9.433e-01  1.060e+00 5.545e-01  1.604791
pos3                        1.128e+00  8.866e-01 9.027e-01  1.409205
pos30                       8.054e-01  1.242e+00 4.215e-01  1.538914
pos31                       9.826e-01  1.018e+00 5.192e-01  1.859717
pos32                       6.311e-01  1.585e+00 3.635e-01  1.095560
pos33                       7.023e-01  1.424e+00 4.125e-01  1.195623
pos34                       1.619e+00  6.177e-01 9.426e-01  2.780753
pos35                       1.084e+00  9.227e-01 5.248e-01  2.238125
pos36                       2.815e+00  3.553e-01 1.320e+00  6.002843
pos37                       8.660e-01  1.155e+00 2.776e-01  2.701762
pos38                       3.132e-01  3.193e+00 1.249e-01  0.785227
pos39                       3.865e-01  2.587e+00 1.009e-01  1.480606
pos4                        1.052e+00  9.502e-01 8.359e-01  1.325066
pos40                       1.683e+00  5.942e-01 4.488e-01  6.310150
pos41                       1.323e+00  7.559e-01 8.518e-01  2.054726
pos42                       1.550e+00  6.451e-01 1.197e+00  2.007838
pos43                       1.391e-04  7.191e+03 1.909e-05  0.001013
pos5                        1.049e+00  9.529e-01 8.277e-01  1.330635
pos6                        1.114e+00  8.980e-01 8.722e-01  1.421808
pos7                        1.093e+00  9.148e-01 8.446e-01  1.414700
pos8                        1.246e+00  8.026e-01 9.356e-01  1.659099
pos9                        1.167e+00  8.566e-01 8.797e-01  1.549322
production_year2000         2.466e+00  4.054e-01 8.137e-01  7.476020
production_year2001         6.756e+00  1.480e-01 1.164e+00 39.228781
production_year2002         1.778e+00  5.624e-01 7.362e-01  4.294561
production_year2003         3.481e+00  2.873e-01 1.300e+00  9.315680
production_year2004         4.337e+00  2.306e-01 1.635e+00 11.503426
production_year2005         5.628e+00  1.777e-01 2.093e+00 15.130713
production_year2006         6.216e+00  1.609e-01 2.946e+00 13.118450
production_year2007         9.250e+00  1.081e-01 4.755e+00 17.993458
production_year2008         7.740e+00  1.292e-01 4.623e+00 12.957732
production_year2009         7.252e+00  1.379e-01 4.494e+00 11.703704
production_year2010         8.400e+00  1.191e-01 5.929e+00 11.899261
production_year2011         8.402e+00  1.190e-01 4.450e+00 15.860286
production_year2012         6.220e+00  1.608e-01 3.225e+00 11.997949
production_year2013         7.360e+00  1.359e-01 3.817e+00 14.189605
production_year2014         6.766e+00  1.478e-01 3.391e+00 13.502482
production_year2015         8.034e+00  1.245e-01 3.891e+00 16.588287
production_year2016         1.187e+01  8.424e-02 5.669e+00 24.858430
production_year2017         1.056e+01  9.467e-02 4.892e+00 22.808638
production_year2018         1.624e+01  6.159e-02 6.702e+00 39.339892

Concordance= 0.629  (se = 0.005 )
Likelihood ratio test= 695.7  on 152 df,   p=<2e-16
Wald test            = 5622  on 152 df,   p=<2e-16
Score (logrank) test = 806.3  on 152 df,   p=<2e-16,   Robust = 715.6  p=<2e-16

  (Note: the likelihood ratio and score tests assume independence of
     observations within a cluster, the Wald and robust score tests do not).
```

I had to remove `unit_type` and `position_in_unit` from the output as this information would lead to identifying product background.

Comment: Could you please show the output from the Cox model directly? The forest plot is hard to read, and that last column should essentially show the same information as the `summary()` output from the Cox model. Please copy that output directly into your question and format it with the `{}` (code) tool on the toolbar so that it's easier to read and so that those who use text-to-speech translation have a chance to follow it.

Comment: @EdM Sure, I added the output. I thought ggforest would simplify the output but as I see them in parallel now, it's even harder to merge this information..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients and p-values for `country` are for the *differences* between each country and some reference country. So the reported coefficients and p-values will depend on what country you (or the software) chose for the reference. If the reference country has a lot of cases and thus a narrow standard error, then it would be easy for a country with a few cases to show a "significant" difference based on just one or a few early failures.

All of your p-values are reported that way, as all of your predictors are categorical, with each report for a difference from the category level set as the reference.

You would better examine the combined overall significance of *all levels* of each predictor. That's conveniently done in the R [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms), whose version of the `anova()` function for its `cph()` Cox models will provide Wald tests incorporating all levels of each predictor.

You also should consider whether you want to include all of those predictors as fixed effects in your model. The problems that you rightly recognize with small numbers of cases in some levels of categorical predictors can be minimized by using random effects and the "partial pooling" of information that entails. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/151800/28500) explains the concept pretty clearly. Then you model the *distribution* of the hazards associated with, say, countries in a way that puts more emphasis on those with more cases.

Comment: very helpful and concrete answer! Thanks a lot again!